# Where to find the list of Fail2Ban built-in port bindings?

Tags: configuration, port, config, fail2ban

I am setting up a fail2ban instance, everything works fine as expected, but I have been noticing some rules has built-in ports, for example:

```
...

[domino-smtp]
port    = smtp,ssmtp
logpath = /home/domino01/data/IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT/console.log

...

filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
port = ssh

...

[phpmyadmin-syslog]
port    = http,https
logpath = %(syslog_authpriv)s
backend = %(syslog_backend)s

...
```

So, when it states that `port` is `ssh` or `http` or whatever, where do fail2ban get these bindings from? How do I know what ports can I use as names and which as just port numbers?

Comment: I haven't used that program in particular, but IANA haves a list of official ports that services use ([Link](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt)). Anything outside that list I'd avoid using.

Answer (score 2):

Named ports are used by many tools besides f2b. In most Linux distributions they are defined in `/etc/services` (a subset of IANA's official list).